# Oracle Performance of SQL with several UNIONS

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

I have a SQL with multiple UNION as follows

```
   select a,c from table1 ......
   UNION
   select a,c from table2 ......
   UNION
   select a,c from table3 ......
   UNION
   select a,c from table4 ......
```

Each of the SQL returns different number of rows, varying from 100 to 200,000

What I have seen is that when these SQL are executed separately, they return results in less than a minute.

But when UNION'ed like show above, they take upto few hours.

Is this because Oracle optimizer is trying to analyze ( in common language terms ) too much information and is not able to figure out best execution plan which fits every SQL ?

Comment: Try adding `distinct` after each `select`

Comment: Sorting of few hundred thousands of records will not explain the difference *of hours*, so you will need to explore the [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122). This is especially relevant if your *tables* are not *tables* but  *complex views*.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not a direct answer, but `UNION` actually does more than just connect the result sets from the various tables, it also removes duplicates.  This can be a costly operation, especially with many large tables.  Assuming you don't mind having duplicates, you could use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT a, c FROM table1 ......
UNION ALL
SELECT a, c FROM table2 ......
UNION ALL
SELECT a, c FROM table3 ......
UNION ALL
SELECT a, c FROM table4 ......
```

`UNION ALL` won't remove duplicates, and will just connect the various result sets without any extra operations.